# Is there a way to rename the android program shortcut on desktop?

Tags: android

In some modified version(for example, CM7), you can long press the shortcut to rename it.
But CM7 have some bugs now.

I would like to know is there a way I can do that? modify the database, change the programs code or resources is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You should find the activity that is launched by this icon and change `android:label` value there. This will change the icon name in Application Launcher and on Home Screen.

It should looks something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloWorld" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The activity definition in `AndroidManifest.xml` should contain `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` in its intent filter (otherwise the activity will not be visible in Application Launcher).